# Unable to add reference in Visual Studio 2012 'ReferenceManagerPackage'

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reference

Recently i encountered this issue whereby whenever i right-click "Add Reference..."
it give me an error as stated below.

Package 'ReferenceManagerPackage' failed to load.

Attempted to reinstall Visual studio 2012 however it still doesn't work.

hasn't meet this issue before.

EDIT:
  
    512
    2013/04/14 00:49:11.860
    Error
    VisualStudio
    CreateInstance failed for package [ReferenceManagerPackage]
    {48D4A2C1-02AD-4F18-9153-620511BACB7B}

---

80131522
    Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsReferenceManager2' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Comment: can you try devenv /resetskipkgs?

Comment: attempted that but thereafter i still get a similar error. stating: The 'ReferenceManagerPackage' package did not load correctly. and thereafter pressing Yes, it state: " The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue before. If I remember the reason for this, basically you have that particular binary in your gac. I'm guessing you recently updated Visual Studio. Although it patched the dll on disk, it is likely loading the dll from the gac, which hasn't been updated. Just regac the dll and you should be fine.

**EDIT**

Sorry, that's my bad. regac isn't an actual command,I just mean you have to add the item to the gac again.

Start a visual studio command prompt and run this command `gacutil /i <path_to_assembly>`,

Comment: yes you are right, i recently updated VS with Update 2.
correct me if i am wrong, regac will required me to put a Assembly as the parameter?

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. regac isn't an actual command,I just mean you have to add the item to the gac again.Star a visual studio command prompt and run this command `gacutil /i <path_to_assembly>`

Comment: but sine i did an update to VS, how do i know which assembly to update to gac?

Comment: The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0 dll

Comment: pardon me for asking again. But can't seem to do it.
after opening the Visual studio cmd, i punched in gacutil /i C:\Windows\assembly\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll
it said "Failure adding assembly to the cache: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @LZH Having same issue. Were you able to fix yours?

Comment: @HaBo nope, instead of wasting hours trying to find a fix, i re-installed the whole VS. not the nicest method though

Comment: @LZH I did the same. Re-install fixed the issue

Answer (score 13):

I just got this error after installation of Visual Studio 2017.

The solution was as follows.

1. Launch `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017`
2. `CD  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`
   -or-
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
3. Run `gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll`

You should now see

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache
```

Restart Visual Studio and hopefully all will be well and you can add references.

The file `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cc9cc69a\ActivityLog.xml` is useful for debugging any other assemblies that may be causing the issue. Annoyingly it's very tempting to click `No` when asked never to see the error message again, which will suppress the error and this path so I thought I'd post it here for reference.

Comment: With some tweaking, this fixed my VS2017! I have VS2017 Professional, so my assemblies were in a different location: 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

Comment: from the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017"
gacutil -i "%devenvdir%\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll"

Comment: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" error is solved with this way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

I've just had the same error (how I got it was different) and adding the assembly back into the GAC did the trick for me. From a VS 2012 command prompt (as admin) I typed...

gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll

Now, my situation differs in that I had to un-install VS 2012 Update 2 (as it had messed up my source control, I couldn't check anything in). After doing a system restore to an earlier date I couldn't open the add-reference dialog in VS 2012. I hunted for this DLL on disk but it was gone, so I copied it from another machine, added it to the GAC and voila, I'm back up and running again.

Comment: using the above command, it throw me this error: "Failure adding assembly to the cache: The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 0):

On my workstation, I don't have the VS Shell Interop DLL, since I don't have Visual Studio SDK installed.  To perform this feat, you'd need to grab SDK from [Download Center -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668).  I bet the problem will go away once it's installed.

To really troubleshoot this, I would attach with another Visual Studio or some other debugger, and set it to break on first chance of Type Load Exception.  Then inspect your call stack and report it here.